How should task be used?
I decided to use verilog task feature to write generic and readable code and I'm having trouble with it.
When I write and call it with Task, it does not see the outputs of the circuit, it only writes 0 to the outputs of the circuit. When I try the same thing without doing a task, it works correctly. What might be causing the problem? What am I missing? In short, instead of doing it over and over again, I want to write a task and call the relevant values ​​within the task. Below is the systemverilog code and TCL console.
without task feature
1-) Code
`include "2in1out_VerilogUDP/ORgate.v"
    
typedef enum logic {
        IN2_OUT1 = 0
}state_t; 


`timescale 1ns/1ps

module test();
    
    // **************************************************ACTUAL RESULTS INTERFACE BEGIN**************************************************
    
    //OR GATE BEGIN
    logic out_ORgate;
    //OR GATE END
    
    
    // **************************************************ACTUAL RESULTS INTERFACE END**************************************************
    
    // **************************************************TEST VECTORS BEGIN**************************************************
    reg InputA, InputB;
    
    //OR GATE BEGIN
    logic ORgate_expected;  
    //OR GATE END


    // **************************************************TEST VECTORS END**************************************************
    
    integer passCount = 0, failCount = 0, DELAY = 100, totalPassCount = 0, totalFailCount = 0, 
            in2out1CellCount = 0;
    
    state_t STATE;

    // **************************************************INSTANCE BEGIN**************************************************
    ORgate_func    ORgate_func    (out_ORgate,    InputA, InputB);
 
    
    // **************************************************INSTANCE END**************************************************
    
    //EXPECTED RESULTS BEGIN
    always_comb begin
        ORgate_expected      = InputA | InputB;
    end 
    //EXPECTED RESULTS END
    
    //STIMULUS GENERATION BEGIN
    initial begin
        $timeformat(-9, 2, "ns");
        forever begin
            #(1ps)
            case(STATE)
                // 2-INPUT 1-OUTPUT CELL STIMULUS GENERATION BEGIN
                IN2_OUT1: begin
                    InputA = 0;
                    InputB = 0;
                    repeat (4) begin
                        #(DELAY)
                        {InputA, InputB} = {InputA, InputB} + 1;
                    end
                end
                // 2-INPUT 1-OUTPUT CELL STIMULUS GENERATION END
            endcase
            
        end
    end 
    //STIMMULUS GENERATION END
    
    
    initial begin
        STATE = IN2_OUT1;
        $display("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t###STANDARD CELL COMPARISON BEGIN###\n");
        // Comparison after a small delay
        #(DELAY/2) 
        wait(!InputA && !InputB); //wait initialization
        $display("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t###ORgate CELL COMPARISON BEGIN###");
        repeat (4) begin
            compare_outputs_2i1o(ORgate_expected, out_ORgate, "out_ORgate");
            #(DELAY);
        end
        displayInformation("ORgate");
        $stop;
    end
    

 
    function void compare_outputs_2i1o(logic expected, actual, string moduleName);
        begin
            if(passCount+failCount < 4)begin 
                assert (expected == actual)begin 
                    passCount = passCount + 1;
                    totalPassCount = totalPassCount + 1;
                    $display("#%0t ##State: PASS## ##Success Attempt:%0d## ##Input Stream => A: %0b B: %0b (%0b%0b)## ##Total Attempt:%0d## Result: %0b Expected Result: %0b", 
                        $realtime, passCount, InputA, InputB, InputA, InputB, passCount + failCount, actual, expected);             
                end
                else begin
                    failCount = failCount + 1;
                    totalFailCount = totalFailCount + 1;
                    $display("#%0T ##State: FAIL##  ##Fail Attempt:%0d## ##Input Stream => A: %0b B: %0b (%0b%0b)## ##Total Attempt:%0d## Result: %0b Expected Result: %0b", 
                        $realtime, passCount, InputA, InputB, InputA, InputB, passCount+failCount, actual, expected);
                end
            end
        end
    endfunction
    
    
    function void displayInformation (string moduleName);
        $display("#%0t %s MODULE TEST COMPLETE ## TEST RESULTS: TOTAL ATTEMPTS:%0d SUCCESSFUL ATTEMPTS:%0d FAILED ATTEMPTS:%0d \n",
            $realtime, moduleName, passCount+failCount, passCount, failCount);
        passCount = 0;
        failCount = 0;
    endfunction
    

endmodule

1-) Output
STANDARD CELL COMPARISON BEGIN

                                                ORgate CELL COMPARISON BEGIN
50.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:1 Input Stream => A: 0 B: 0 (00) Total Attempt:1 Result: 0 Expected Result: 0
150.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:2 Input Stream => A: 0 B: 1 (01) Total Attempt:2 Result: 1 Expected Result: 1
250.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:3 Input Stream => A: 1 B: 0 (10) Total Attempt:3 Result: 1 Expected Result: 1
350.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:4 Input Stream => A: 1 B: 1 (11) Total Attempt:4 Result: 1 Expected Result: 1
450.00ns ORgate MODULE TEST COMPLETE  TEST RESULTS: TOTAL ATTEMPTS:4 SUCCESSFUL ATTEMPTS:4 FAILED ATTEMPTS:0 

with task feature
2-) Code
`include "2in1out_VerilogUDP/ORgate.v"
    
typedef enum logic {
        IN2_OUT1 = 0
}state_t; 


`timescale 1ns/1ps

module test();
    
    // **************************************************ACTUAL RESULTS INTERFACE BEGIN**************************************************
    
    //OR GATE BEGIN
    logic out_ORgate;
    //OR GATE END
    
    
    // **************************************************ACTUAL RESULTS INTERFACE END**************************************************
    
    // **************************************************TEST VECTORS BEGIN**************************************************
    reg InputA, InputB;
    
    //OR GATE BEGIN
    logic ORgate_expected;  
    //OR GATE END


    // **************************************************TEST VECTORS END**************************************************
    
    integer passCount = 0, failCount = 0, DELAY = 100, totalPassCount = 0, totalFailCount = 0, 
            in2out1CellCount = 0;
    
    state_t STATE;

    // **************************************************INSTANCE BEGIN**************************************************
    ORgate_func    ORgate_func    (out_ORgate,    InputA, InputB);
 
    
    // **************************************************INSTANCE END**************************************************
    
    //EXPECTED RESULTS BEGIN
    always_comb begin
        ORgate_expected      = InputA | InputB;
    end 
    //EXPECTED RESULTS END
    
    //STIMULUS GENERATION BEGIN
    initial begin
        $timeformat(-9, 2, "ns");
        forever begin
            #(1ps)
            case(STATE)
                // 2-INPUT 1-OUTPUT CELL STIMULUS GENERATION BEGIN
                IN2_OUT1: begin
                    InputA = 0;
                    InputB = 0;
                    repeat (4) begin
                        #(DELAY)
                        {InputA, InputB} = {InputA, InputB} + 1;
                    end
                end
                // 2-INPUT 1-OUTPUT CELL STIMULUS GENERATION END
            endcase
            
        end
    end 
    //STIMMULUS GENERATION END
    
    
    initial begin
        
        STATE = IN2_OUT1;
        $display("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t###STANDARD CELL COMPARISON BEGIN###\n");
        // Comparison after a small delay
         #(DELAY/2) 
         wait(!InputA && !InputB); //wait initialization

        dummy_2i1o(ORgate_expected, out_ORgate, "ORgate");
        displayInformation("ORgate");

        $stop;
    end
    

 
    function void compare_outputs_2i1o(logic expected, actual, string moduleName);
        begin
            if(passCount+failCount < 4)begin 
                assert (expected == actual)begin 
                    passCount = passCount + 1;
                    totalPassCount = totalPassCount + 1;
                    $display("#%0t ##State: PASS## ##Success Attempt:%0d## ##Input Stream => A: %0b B: %0b (%0b%0b)## ##Total Attempt:%0d## Result: %0b Expected Result: %0b", 
                        $realtime, passCount, InputA, InputB, InputA, InputB, passCount + failCount, actual, expected);             
                end
                else begin
                    failCount = failCount + 1;
                    totalFailCount = totalFailCount + 1;
                    $display("#%0T ##State: FAIL##  ##Fail Attempt:%0d## ##Input Stream => A: %0b B: %0b (%0b%0b)## ##Total Attempt:%0d## Result: %0b Expected Result: %0b", 
                        $realtime, passCount, InputA, InputB, InputA, InputB, passCount+failCount, actual, expected);
                end
            end
        end
    endfunction
    
    
    function void displayInformation (string moduleName);
        $display("#%0t %s MODULE TEST COMPLETE ## TEST RESULTS: TOTAL ATTEMPTS:%0d SUCCESSFUL ATTEMPTS:%0d FAILED ATTEMPTS:%0d \n",
            $realtime, moduleName, passCount+failCount, passCount, failCount);
        passCount = 0;
        failCount = 0;
    endfunction
    
    task dummy_2i1o(logic expected, actual, string moduleName);
        begin
            $display("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t###%s CELL COMPARISON BEGIN###", moduleName);
            repeat(4) begin 
                
                compare_outputs_2i1o(expected, actual, moduleName);
                #(DELAY);
            end
        end
    endtask 

endmodule

2-) Output
                                                
                                                STANDARD CELL COMPARISON BEGIN

                                                ORgate CELL COMPARISON BEGIN
50.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:1 Input Stream => A: 0 B: 0 (00) Total Attempt:1 Result: 0 Expected Result: 0
150.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:2 Input Stream => A: 0 B: 1 (01) Total Attempt:2 Result: 0 Expected Result: 0
250.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:3 Input Stream => A: 1 B: 0 (10) Total Attempt:3 Result: 0 Expected Result: 0
350.00ns State: PASS Success Attempt:4 Input Stream => A: 1 B: 1 (11) Total Attempt:4 Result: 0 Expected Result: 0
450.00ns ORgate MODULE TEST COMPLETE # TEST RESULTS: TOTAL ATTEMPTS:4 SUCCESSFUL ATTEMPTS:4 FAILED ATTEMPTS:0 



In this example, you need to pass the task arguments by reference.
task dummy_2i1o(ref logic expected, actual, input string moduleName);

Normally the default mode of a task argument is an input passed by value. That means the value of the variables passed to the task is copied upon entering the task, but as time marches forward inside the task, they are never updated after that.
By using a ref, any reference to the formal argument inside the task is actually a reference to the variable used in the task call. So it always has the updated value.
A note of warning: there are more restrictions passing by ref. You can only pass variables (not expressions or wires) by reference, and the type type of the variable passed must match the type of the formal argument (logic cannot be passed to a bit). Only use pass by reference where you need this behavior.
